# Parallelization of inner "do loop" inside a "do while loop" with openmp

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a code that in pseudo is sth like this:

```
Do while loop
  if condition
    call subroutinex(In)
  else
    do i=2,max
      ln=i
      call subroutinex(ln)
    end do
  endif
  other serial work
end do
```

I have managed to succesfully parallelize the inner loop like that

```
Do while loop
  if condition
    call subroutinex(In)
  else
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT (SHARED) PRIVATE (pr.variables)
!$OMP DO
    do i=2,max
      ln=i
      call subroutinex(ln)
    end do
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
  endif
  other serial work
end do
```

This code works fine for me producing the correct results, and running at about half the time of the optimized auto parallelized NO-OMP version (for max=5). I suspect (though not quite sure about it) that spawning the parallel region within the "Do while loop" may be causing some unnecessary overhead that I can avoid using a different approach (spawning the parallel region outside the outer loop and using !$OMP CRITICAL or !$OMP MASTER). I can't seem to understand how the correct syntax would be for sth like that though. Any suggestions are very welcome.

Best regards,
Apostolos

Answer (score 0):

I think this modification of your pseudocode ought to work

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT (SHARED) PRIVATE (pr.variables)
Do while loop
  if condition
    !$OMP SINGLE
    call subroutinex(In)
    !$OMP END SINGLE
  else
!$OMP DO
    do i=2,max
      ln=i
      call subroutinex(ln)
    end do
!$OMP END DO
  endif
  !$OMP SINGLE
  other serial work
  !$OMP END SINGLE
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

You'll need to check accessibility of variables carefully.

This might not deliver significant speed-up.  The overhead of entering a parallel region typically does not include time to start up a team of threads, but to activate the team that was established on program initialisation.  But do report back and let me know if this (a) works and (b) improves the execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can explore OpenMP tasks, e.g.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT (SHARED) PRIVATE (pr.variables)
!$OMP SINGLE
Do while loop
  if condition
    call subroutinex(In)
  else
    do i=2,max
      ln=i
!$OMP TASK firstprivate(ln)
      call subroutinex(ln)
!$OMP END TASK
    end do
!$OMP TASKWAIT
  endif
  other serial work
end do
!$OMP END SINGLE nowait
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```